# Ehcache-spring-annotations @Cacheable not catching method with String object as parameter

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am using **ehcache-spring-annotations-1.2.0.jar .**
This is my cache.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

    <ehcache:annotation-driven />



    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"/>



</beans>
```

This is my ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

        <cache name="messageCache" eternal="false"
        maxElementsInMemory="5" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="1000" timeToLiveSeconds="3000"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

This is my main code

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable;

public class EcacheSpringtest {
    private static ApplicationContext cachecontext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("cache.xml");

    @Cacheable(cacheName = "messageCache")
    String getName(String name) {

        System.out.println(name+ " "+"has not been found in the cache so called getName()");
        return "testObject";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long starttime;
        long endtime;
        long calldifferencesecs;

        EcacheSpringtest test = new EcacheSpringtest();
        test.getName("test");
        try {
            starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(150);
            endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            calldifferencesecs = starttime - endtime ;
            System.out.println("preparing to call getName with test as paramter after" +" "+ (~calldifferencesecs)+1 +"milliseconds");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        test.getName("test"); // In this case testObject should be returned from cache  but it is again calling getName().The method getName() is again called when same "test" String object is passed to method after 1491 milliseconds.

    }
}
```

I have taken reference from

http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/spring-annotations

https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable

**EditFirst** Implementing the solution given below by kabochkov I have tested it   .But also i am unable to cache.

I could not figure out where i have done mistake.Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create object directly, spring can't handle @Cacheable annotation.

```
EcacheSpringtest test = new EcacheSpringtest();
```

Use dependency injection and it will work!

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:cache.xml"})
public abstract class TestEcacheSpring {

  @Autowired
  EcacheSpringtest test;

  @Test
  public void test(){
    test.getName("test");
    test.getName("test"); 
  }

}
```

EcacheSpringtest shoul'd be marked as @Service

```
@Service
public class EcacheSpringtest {

@Cacheable(cacheName = "messageCache")
String getName(String name) {
 System.out.println(name+ " "+"has not been found in the cache so called getName()");
 return "testObject";
}

}
```

Comment: Would you please little elaborate this code .I have not done testing like this way.Thank you.

Comment: Kabochkov is right : you must instanciate your beans with Spring if you want to use Spring. SO caching will only work with Spring instanciation. Using new won't. Check the Spring samples more carefully and read Spring documentation to learn Spring basics before trying to use the caching feature.

Comment: I followed the suggestion given by kabochkov .I tested this time using junit test with  @Autowired    EcacheSpringtest but also i am not able to cache.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you are using thirdparty spring cache library. Try native spring soulution. See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/spring-31-cache-abstraction-tutorial.html

Answer (score 7):

I finally solved the problem.What mistake i was doing was that according to documentation 
https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable
It was written 
**You can place the @Cacheable annotation on a method on an interface, or a public method on a class**. So before my method was not public .So i changed it to public and it worked.

Comment: No second version as solution given by you.Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I doubt here is that there is no reference at all to your ehcache.xml in your context.

I have used ehcache in production with following configuration in `context.xml` and it works perfectly.

Could you try after adding following to context (Note: You'll have to remove  `<ehcache:annotation-driven />` and also add spring-cache xmlns to context)

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="true" />
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml" p:shared="true" />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache" />
```

Add
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"

xsi:http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd

Comment: i added this code in my xml file 
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"

xsi:http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd   and it show me error  "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:annotation-driven'." can you help me how can i solve this problem visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826832/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-eh