# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:annotation-driven'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

```
I used spring cache in my application . XML file where i configure ehcache is as below : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd ">

This is code for declaring bean for ehcache . But this code create problem 
and so me error message "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:annotation-driven'."


<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
    <bean id="ehCacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/config/ehcache.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have used google cache url but it so me error message 2 days before . on searching internet i found that google shut down this service. and he suggest to me add spring cache and add these line in your code

Add
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"

xsi:http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd

After adding code it show me error :

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:annotation-driven'.

Can anyone help me how can i resolve this problem .

Comment: Don't ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818099/multiple-annotations-found-the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-c?noredirect=1#comment63102257_37818099) each day...

Comment: @M.Deinum this not same question i facing other problem in it . Please can you guide me how i move my google ehcache to spring

Comment: I already answered that in the previous question (which is still the exact same).